# Displaying all navigation properties of a record in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I currently have a one to many relationship and I would like to display all of the navigation properties of a record as a string in a table. The relationship looks like this:

[image: Relationship]

The current table created in an old web forms page that I'm trying to recreate in MVC looks like this:

[image: Table]

How can I list each navigation property like the table above? I've tried using SelectMany(x=>x.CHCASNumber.CASNumber) but it just prints the System.Linq.Enumerable line:

[image: New table]

This is how my method is created. Maybe slow and inefficient but I'm receptive to improving it.

```cs
[OpenAction]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChemicalInventory(AlertModel successAlert, AlertModel failureAlert)
    {
        var chemicals = (from c in await LimsManager.AllAsync<CHChemical>(s => s.CHCASNumbers) select c).ToList();

        var chemicalModel = chemicals.Select(s =>  new ChemicalModel
        {
           Data = chemicals,
           CASNumbers = GetCASNumbers(s.Id)

        }).ToList();

       return PartialView("_CHChemicalTable", chemicalModel);
    }
    
[OpenAction]
private List<string> GetCASNumbers(int chemicalId)
    {
      return (from c in LimsManager.All<CHCASNumbers>()
              where c.ChemicalId == chemicalId
              select c.CASNumber).ToList();
    }
```

And the model:

```cs
public class ChemicalModel 
    {
        public List<CHChemical> Data { get; set; }
        public List<string> CASNumbers { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is the navigation property in the debugger:
Hopefully it's easier to tell what I'm trying to show.

[image: Debugger]

(The LIMSManager method is a custom method for accessing EF6)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Your model should include complete data before it goes to the view. Anyways, have you tried using the include() method?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: @Arsalan getting to the navigation property isn't a problem. It's printing all navigation property data in the view like the web forms table above is what I'm trying to do. I'll put a picture of the drilldown menu in my original question.

Comment: @gunr2171 I updated my original question and removed the pictures of code

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var model = new ChemicalModel
        {
            CASNumbers = new List<string>{
               "123-96-6",
               "7732-18-5"
           }
        };

        string s = model.CASNumbers.Aggregate(string.Empty, (sum, val) => sum + val + ", ");
        Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2));
    }
}



public class ChemicalModel
{
    public List<CHChemical> Data { get; set; }
    public List<string> CASNumbers { get; set; }

}

public class CHChemical
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).